# Is questions on geogebra on-topic?

Tags: support, on-topic-definition, asking-questions

I've got some questions regarding geogebra (about tool options in geogebra), and wanted to know if this is the right SE site.

Some questions I have are of type "How to draw this (eg:curve) in geogebra?"
Some other questions are specific to geogebra and off-topic here.

Are the first type of questions on-topic in Graphic Design website?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While Geogebra allows you to create graphics, it’s primarily a scientific and educational software and as such used by scientists, math teachers and students, but not by graphic designers. Creating something with Geogebra requires knowledge about geometrical construction and similar mathematical concepts and thus poses entirely different challenges than creating something with a typical graphic-design software. (The only reason I am familiar with this software is through my day job as a scientist.) Therefore, we are not a community that is good at answering questions about this software or judging them – which is [the most basic definition of *off-topic*](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3284/19174).

Currently the following Stack Exchange sites have a Geogebra tag:

- [Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/geogebra) (1 question) – This seems the best fitting site to me, but there is not much going on.
- [TeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geogebra) (27 questions) – This appears to be about TeX integration of Geogebra and thus not suited for every question.
- [WebApps](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geogebra) (1 question) – This seems like a mistake.
- [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/geogebra) (30 questions) – This seems to be due to the fact, that Geogebra is programmable.
- Math SE doesn’t have a Geogebra tag, but currently it is mentioned in [thousand questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=Geogebra), many of which appear to be about actual Geogebra usage. According to [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9073/65502), such questions should be on topic there.

I therefore think the latter two sites are your best choice among SE sites, but probably [the Geogebra forum](https://help.geogebra.org/) is your best choice when it comes to questions about this specific software.

The only kind of question that I consider suitable here is one which does not care about the software you use, e.g.: “How can I make this diagram more accessible?”

Comment: I am surprised to see that geogebra related questions are comparatively well received in math.se. But, my question is on use of geogebra as a drawing software.

Comment: @CyriacAntony: I find it not so surprising, once you think of SE scopes being about a community and not about the dictionary definition of some topice. Geogebra experts certainly form a subset of the expert target audience of Math SE. It’s a software made for mathematicians; it draws things mathematically. Suppose you were stuck drawing something with Geogebra, had no Internet and could ask only one of the following: a graphic designer, a general software expert, or a mathematician. Whom would you choose?

Answer (score 1):

For general guidance on what is on topic here please see [What topics can I ask about here?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

To be honest, I don't think any how-to questions regarding Geogebra are on topic on this site. It is first and foremorst a *mathematical* tool. Some mathematical questions might be best answered in a visual way, yet that does not mean it is a graphic design problem.

I would imagine a question like "How to draw this in geogebra?" to be off-topic, since the output will be decided by a mathematical way of thinking, not a design one. Such questions would be better asked on mathematical fora, such as [Math SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), or maybe on [Computer Graphics](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). (Beware though that SE is not intended as a 'solve my homework' tool).

A question that *could* fit here would be: "What is the best way to present these line charts so that they fit my style guide,  but remain clear and scientifically correct?" since that question requires a *design* way of thinking. The fact that a mathematical process led to the generation of the graphics bears no impact on the design problem of presentation.

I hope I am making myself clear? It is all about the inherent problem.

- Is it a mathematical one: not a good fit.
- Is it a design one: good fit.
- Is it a bit of both: ask away and let the community decide.

Comment: Okay. My questions are not math related; but rather related to drawing. But they are specific to geogebra (which is still off-topic according to [def. of on-topic](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)). I am sure such questions are off-topic in math.se. They seem to be off-topic in cg.se too (i suppose this website is for questions related to the area of computer graphics rather than graphic softwares).

Comment: OK, if you think your question is on-topic, then please ask away. At the end of the day, it is the community that decides with upvotes, downvotes and close votes.

Answer (score 0):

It is ok to ask about geogebra as a drawing application. The problem is that your question is asking for a opinion. This too on this case is in my opinion OK. Its perfectly valid to ask a question on wether you should use software or not.

Its just that the answer to a question like this is super banal:

1. use it if you find it useful
2. if not use something else or
3. use geogebra and something else.

Mathematical thinking is OK for designing. A lot of illustrator questions on this site are ultimately math questions. But i doubt you will find many users interested in such questions though. So while its not offtopic its ultimately slightly disinteresting for the community at large.